# Need help processing CHAR strings with printf

Tags: c, avr

I'm using softserial to communicate with a bluetooth modem and I am pushing strings to the serial by using the following code:

```
char bt_string = "test";
bluetooth_println(bt_string);
```

I need to be able to replace the string with

```
printf("  Error: cmd=%02hX, res=%02hX\n", CMD_SEND_CID, res);
```

I have tried the following code

```
char bt_string;
sprintf(bt_string, "  Error: cmd=%02hX, res=%02hX\n", CMD_SEND_CID, res);
bluetooth_println(bt_string);
```

But it fails to output anything. I'm obviously misunderstanding something. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide a buffer for your string.

```
char bt_string[256]; // <-- or any size that you are sure will be enough for what you will put in.
```

eventually, for safety you can use `snpritf` to avoid any buffer overflow:

```
#define MAX_BT_STRING 256
char bt_string[MAX_BT_STRING];
snprintf(bt_string, MAX_BT_STRING,"  Error: cmd=%02hX, res=%02hX\n", CMD_SEND_CID, res);
bluetooth_println(bt_string);
```

Comment: Thank you. Always something simple. Works great

Answer (score 1):

`char *str` and `char str[]` are distinctly different. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1704407/3824053) for more details.

In your problem, you declared bt_string as `const char *bt_string = "test"`, where `bt_string` is pointer which points to the first char in string "test". This string has a size of 5 bytes(don't forget the terminator \0);

In the next step:

```
sprintf(bt_string, "  Error: cmd=%02hX, res=%02hX\n", CMD_SEND_CID, res);
```

You dump more than 5 bytes to bt_string which only has 5 bytes available space. The parts beyond 5 bytes will overwrite the contents after bt_string, which may lead to some serious situation or nothing, it depends on what is followed.

To settle this problem, you have to allocate enough memory space:

1. allocate on stack as A.S.H answered. the content is determined after function finished.
2. allocate via malloc;
3. use static key word to force the string stored either in BSS section or DATA section.

Comment: thank you for seeing that. It was a typo when entering the question.